# AngularJS external javascript libraries do not run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

First off I do apologize if this is already answered somewhere.

I am having an issue with AngularJS and external libs. For some reason when I attempt to have an external lib preform any sort of visual operation on an element it simply does not run.

One of such external libraries is the jscolor library which adds a really simplistic color picker (source link: http://jscolor.com)

Here is the include code in my index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/css/style.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>

<script src="app/js/lib/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script src="app/js/services/drawCanvas.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/services/colorpicker.js"></script>

<script src="app/js/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/components/drawableComponent.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/components/navigationComponent.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/components/canvasComponent.js"></script>
```

As you can see I do have jscolor.min.js included and I can assure you the file is there.

Here is the code in the relative component that contains the input that I am attempting to attach the JS color to.

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.component('drawable', {
        templateUrl: 'app/js/components/drawableComponent.html',
        controller: ['$rootScope','$scope', function ElementController($rootScope, $scope){
            var self = this;

            $scope.drawables = [];

            self.$onInit = function() {
                //$scope.drawables.push("test");
            }

            $scope.addDrawable = function(type, css) {

                $scope.drawables.push({type:type,css:css});
                console.log($scope.drawables);
            }


            $rootScope.$on("pushDrawable", function(event, args){
               $scope.addDrawable(args.type,args.css);

            });

            self.animateTooltip = function(e) {
                $(e.target).find(".draggableTooltip").toggle("slow").css("transform", "translateY(-60%)");
            }




        }
        ]

    });
})();
```

Here is the template that is included in this controller (what angular calls when the component is included)

```
<div class="draggable" ng-repeat="drag in drawables track by $index" style="{{drag.css}}" ng-click="$ctrl.animateTooltip($event)">
    <div class="draggableTooltip" style="display:none" >This is a tooltip <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567"></div>
    <p> You can drag one element </p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am attempting to include jscolor just like they explain in the examples on the jscolor documentation (honestly the implementation of this color picker should be simple and I have no doubts that I am doing it correctly, The calling and implementing that is)

What happens specifically is the input element is a simple text field much like what is shown on jscolor's site. However clicking that element and giving it focus does not launch the color picker as expected.

This is just one example of issues that I have had, another issue I have had and still do have is accordion nav menus dont animate slide down, or function at all whilst inside of a component's template. I think it has something to do with how angular injects templates, however I am wondering if someone can help me out with more experience as to show me the correct way of getting these external libraries to work.

Since the issue is a tad more complex I wasnt able to set up a jsfiddle.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you calling it from angular?

Comment: Any error on the developer tool (f12)?

Comment: @Aravind, I am not calling it from angular the idea is that at this point I do not have the time to make these into factories so I want to keep the code itself separate. In a fully functioning release build I will convert all my external libs into factories.

Comment: @kyorilys No errors unfortunately, on both Chrome and Firefox (firebug)

Comment: @POSEIDON I am not getting your point

Comment: @Aravind my point was to answer your question, I am not calling it in angular like you would normally call another module, or a factory. Because it is not yet made into either of those, it is a stand alone lib.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

https://ruhley.github.io/angular-color-picker/

It's fully integrated in angular without dependencies on jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this link, I was going to develop my own color picker and integrate it as a factory but I couldnt find anything like this and I only wanted a simple functionality for angular. So this helps a bunch! However the problem with other external libraries still exists, looking to see if anyone else knows what to do about this angular -> other libs conflict.

Comment: Bootstrap.js, jscolor, materializejs. Pretty much any js lib that is not created into an angular factory or controller doesnt let animations work if you attempt to use their functionality. That is the problem I am trying to figure out what part of angular causes that. Once I know I can create an active work around. Yes I do know by the way that both bootstrap and materialize have Angular UI builds to give functionality. Using those doesnt solve my problem if I want to use an external lib without making it into a factory. Having said that, I have implemented the Bootstrap angular ui for now.